# Foreign Key to User model

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I want to create a new model, something like:

```py
user_name = models.ForeignKey(u"Username", User),
```

but when I try to syncdb, I get this error message:

```
"AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'"
```

When I look at some tutorials, everything seems to be the same as in my model, and the problem with `_meta` is never mentioned.

Comment: I finaly found out. It was my stupid mistake. I had in my another model: class Meta: verbose_name = smart_encode(u"something). Sorry about that and thank You both!

Answer (score 40):

A safer way to do this is to use the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` from the settings file.

Example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    article = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

By default `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` refers to `django.contrib.auth.models.User` without requiring you to do anything.

The **advantage** of this approach is that your app will continue to work even if you use a custom user model without modification.

For more information on how to make use of custom user models [check out this part of the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: is it possible to restrict the foreign key? so what if I only want the foreign key to relate to a group of users?

Comment: @CameronTaylor Yes, that is possible. Use [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) to restrict the choice to certain group of users.

Answer (score 26):

You just want:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want and what I did, but this solution raises AttributeError as mentioned in my Question.

Comment: @Meph can you not see the difference between what you have and what Joe has? Hint: look at the first parameter to the ForeignKey.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I can, but it does not matter. Same error with Joes solution

Comment: You'll need to post your full model then.

Comment: you'll need to add "from django.contrib.auth.models import User" at the top of the file.

Comment: I'm assuming the questioner knows this otherwise they wouldn't be able to ask the question.