# foreignkey (user) in models

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I read the docs and this post... [Django - Foreign Key to User model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309588/django-foreign-key-to-user-model)

I followed what it said and I still cannot get it to work. When I try to run the migrations I get this error in the traceback...

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "author_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING author_id::integer".
```

I just don't know how to go about fixing that error.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class BlogCategory(models.Model):
    '''model for categories'''

    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class BlogPost(models.Model):
    '''a model for a blog post'''

    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Are you using the default user model? Please include the relevant migration file

Answer (score -14, accepted):

I do not know the "settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL" approach but a well-known approach and commonly used is the "Auth.User" model. Something like this on your end.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    '''a model for a blog post'''

    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post = models.TextField()
```

Comment: I tried that before looking it up and doing the other way. I get the same error

Comment: Providing you haven't overridden the [`AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-user-model), the model you're referring to *is* the default

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model, as what the link says the "AUTH_USER_MODEL"  should be the user model of a certain app, have you done that on your end? Or you might want to provide other extra details like the value of your AUTH_USER_MODEL

Comment: I have not defined a user model for that class. Is there not some way to make it a foreign key to all users in my database?

Comment: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

author = models.ForeignKey(User)

is the best answer I got for you in your case as it is what I have always used

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada I get the same error when I use that way

Comment: I just tried it and emptied out the database of the previous post entries

Comment: I don't understand what happened here. The code in this answer looks like a snippet from the one in the question.

Answer (score 170):

Don't use the `User` model directly.

From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

> Instead of referring to `User` directly, you should reference the user
>   model using `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()`
>
> When you define a foreign key or many-to-many relations to the user model, you should specify the custom model using the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting.

Example:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

Comment: One thing that confused me when using this answer was whether or not I needed to define the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting in `settings.py`. Documentation says that is not necessary - `This method will return the currently active user model – the custom user model if one is specified, or User otherwise.`

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) states: "Django allows you to override the default user model by providing a value for the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting". Basically: *if* you are providing a custom `User` model you *must* provide the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting.

Answer (score 4):

If you created a custom User model, you would use `setting.AUTH_USER_MODEL`, if not you can go ahead an use `User model`

[Referencing Django User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model)

Comment: what if presently not using custom model and in future there are chances to use which option will be better then?

Comment: Always go with using a custom user model from the initial setup, because it will be difficult making the changes later on.

Answer (score 0):

the column "author_id" doesn't exist, looks like is the same problem from here : [Django suffix ForeignKey field with _id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116130/django-suffix-foreignkey-field-with-id) , so to avoid this traceback you may use :

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column="user")
```