# Social-auth-django with custom uer model use OneToOneField link to auth.User

Tags: django, python-social-auth, django-socialauth, social-auth-app-django

I have a customer model extends django auth.User like:

```
class CustomerUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                related_name='customeruser',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    secondary_email = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique=True, null=True)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        db_index=True
    )
```

In my setting.py:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.models.CustomerUser'
```

and err msg look like:

`ValueError: Invalid model reference 'account.models.CustomerUser'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.`

What should I do that I can craete a customeruser and make it references to auth.User?

Answer (score 0):

replace User with `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`
and add
from django.conf import settings

```
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

[help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40954392/11602126)

Comment: I do something below    
    
in ```accounts/models.py```     
```class CustomerUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                related_name='customeruser',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    secondary_email = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique=True, null=True)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        db_index=True
    )```

Comment: in ```settings.py```  
```AUTH_USER_MODEL='auth.User'
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.CustomerUser'```  


It work!  
but when I use github oauth login my web,it said below:  

```FieldDoesNotExist at /social-auth/complete/github/
CustomerUser has no field named 'username'```  
  
  
I think that social-auth should create a instance in table auth.User and a instance in table CustomerUser.
  

but it seems like not do as I think.